Find algebraically independent elements $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ such that $B = k[X, X^{-1}]$ is integral over $k[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Find algebraically independent elements $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ such that $B = k[X, X^{-1}]$ is integral over $k[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$.

We want to find a polynomial with coefficients in $k[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$ such that $X$ and $X^{-1}$ are integral over this ring.
The idea of Noether's lemma is to find a subset of algebraically independent elements over $k$ such that the ring $k[X, X^{-1}]$ is a finite extension of these elements. The element $Z = X + X^{-1}$ is useful because $Z$ is transcendental over $k$, which implies it is algebraically independent over $k$.
Then, we find that the polynomial $f(Y) = Y^2 - ZY + 1$ evaluated at both $X$ and $X^{-1}$ is zero:
\begin{gather*}
    f(X) = X^2 - (X + X^{-1})X + 1 = X^2 - X^2 - 1 + 1 = 0 \\
    f(X^{-1}) = X^{-2} - (X + X^{-1})X^{-1} + 1 = X^{-2} - 1 - X^{-2} + 1 = 0
\end{gather*}
Thus, $X$ and $X^{-1}$ are integral over $k[X + X^{-1}]$ and, therefore, $k[X, X^{-1}]$ is integral over $k[X + X^{-1}]$.
Is the proof I have followed correct? Does it fully demonstrate that $k[X, X^{-1}]$ is integral over $k[X + X^{-1}]$ by finding the algebraically independent element $Z = X + X^{-1}$ and showing $X$ and $X^{-1}$ are integral over $k[Z]$?

Yes. Argument is correct and complete.
